# Imacros - check if text exits (javascript)

Tags: javascript, text, imacros

I've searched so many posts already, and still can't get this to work.

What i need is to simply check if a certain word exists on the website. (Imacros for Firefox) using javascript.

I've seen some answers saying to use "document.". That doesn't work. 
I've seen some saying use "window.document". That gives an error which says it's not supported in multiprocess firefox.
And some said to do similar stuff which also doesn't work.

I've also found this;

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

iimPlay(macro)

var text=iimGetLastExtract();

if(text.search("Hello World")!=-1)
{
    alert("Found the text");
}
```

^Where the script just runs and...finishes. It doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't throw an alert. It just ends.

So how could i do this?

Comment: Are `iimPlay` and `iimGetLastExtract` defined somewhere?

Comment: It's in iMacros, when you use iimPlay("example.iim"); in the javascript file, it will run the .iim file located in Documents/iMacros

Answer (score 0):

If you did not have the SET !ERRORIGNORE YES command in your macro, you would see that iMacros is throwing an 'allocation size overflow' exception, most likely because the amount of text it is extracting is too much for it to handle.

But I just tested your script with a previous version of iMacros for Firefox and it does not have this problem, so it must be a bug with the current version (9.0.3). In this case, I would recommend downgrading to the previous version (8.9.7):

http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#How_to_Downgrade

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rather forget that a web page may contain several frames, so try the following script on this page first:

```
for (i = 0; ; i++) {
    var ret = iimPlayCode("SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1" + "\n" + "FRAME F=" + i + "\n" + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT");
    if (ret != 1) {
        // alert("Not found the text");
        break;
    }

    if (iimGetExtract().indexOf("Imacros - check if text exits (javascript)") > -1) {
        alert("Found the text");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: still doesn't seem to alert me of anything in any way, the script runs, and finishes and stops. Could you explain a bit?

Update: I've tested the script with 'iimDisplay();' instead of 'alert' ,and, it always displays the message where the 'if (ret != 1)' code is, regardless of 'Hello World' existing or not, and never displays the 'if(iimGetExtract().search' message.

Comment: @DenisDelinger. see the explanation in my answer. It's very likely that the macro is returning error code -1001 due to the 'allocation size overflow' bug. You can see the return value by calling alert(ret) after the iimPlayCode call. You will also see it if you run the macro directly in the browser and not from a .js script. I'm fairly certain that you will need to downgrade to get this to work correctly.

Comment: I've edited my code a little. Just try to play it on this page. Does it work for you?